# How to use the same ANTLR grammar file for both frontend and backend?

Tags: package, antlr

I have two copies of the ANTLR grammar written in a **.g4** file used by the frontend and the application layer. Frontend uses it in a React NodeJs package for Intellisense and Syntax validation. Application layer uses a copy of the same file in a Java package for evaluating the expressions passed from the front end. Is there any way I can use a single instance of these grammar files in both the packages of different build types, so that the change management will be easier ?

Comment: Why two? The goal of v4 is to support a single grammar file for different target languages.

Comment: @LexLi We are using it in a web app, where frontend performs validation check and autocomplete for users and backend for converting the identified expressions to executable tasks.

Comment: How you use the generated parser code is irrelevant to this question. The same g4 file can generate both Java and JavaScript parser code (if you strictly remove all embedded actions and use listener/visitor instead).

Comment: @LexLi it is the same file, but different copies of it. one existing in a file in a java package and another as a file in a Node Js package. As both are of different build system, am not sure how to share this file between the two.

Comment: There can be several options. One is to put the grammar file in a single Git repo, and generate both JavaScript/Java code from there, and then use this repo as submodule in your front end/back end repos.

Comment: KVM, what do you mean by "package" here? Repositories? Directories? Something else? As long as both code bases live inside the same repo, I see no reason why you'd need two copies of the file. If they're different repos, it makes sense to move the grammar in a third repo as LexLi suggested (but I don't think you need to generate the code there if you use submodules - either include the grammar as a submodule and generate the code in the parent projects; or have the grammar repo be its own project that publishes the parser as NPM and Maven modules which you then use in the other projects).

Comment: @sepp2k that makes sense. Having a package which will have one grammar file and will generate both the NPM and Maven modules. The only challenge is, in our company each package can have only one build system assigned to it. Need to find a work around for that. However please consider adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Place the grammars into a location which can be accessed by both, the frontend and the backend and reference them from there.